# MySQL join only when condition is met one time

Tags: mysql, left-join, multiple-tables

There probably is a simple solution but I can't wrap my head around it.

Let's say we have 4 tables
persons (id, is_teacher)
persons_relation (id, person_id, teacher_id)
rooms_relation (id, person_id, room_id)
rooms (id) (not used here)

persons can be either teachers or students.
if a person is a teacher they can have multiple students assigned via persons_relation.
a person can be assigned to many rooms, directly or through their teacher (so person->room or person(no teacher)->person(teacher)->room).

I want to find the persons that ARE NOT assigned to ANY room, neither directly nor via a teacher who has a room assigned. But my query also returns persons who are assigned to teachers of which some have rooms and some don't. So if one of those teachers has a room assigned I don't want the student returned here.

```
SELECT * FROM persons p
LEFT JOIN rooms_relation r ON r.person_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN persons_relation pr ON pr.person_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN rooms_relation tr ON tr.person_id = pr.teacher_id
WHERE tr.id IS NULL AND r.id IS NULL;
```

Example:

- person 1 is student
- persons 7,8,9 are teachers
- student is assigned to teachers 7, 8, and 9 (via persons_relation)
- student has no room assigned
- teachers 7 and 9 have rooms assigned to them (via rooms_relation)
- teacher 8 has no room assigned (this is the problem)

Since student has at least one room assigned via teachers 7 and 9 he should not be returned.
But since teacher 8 has no room assigned, there is a row where tr.id IS NULL so he gets returned. I don't want that.

(I'm aware that I could've used only one join for rooms but I )

Comment: You must aggregate over a student and count the amount of rooms. If it is positive then the row should not be returned.

Answer (score 0):

`I want to find the persons that ARE NOT assigned to ANY room`

The following query will list out the persons who are not in `rooms_relation` table. Isnt it that you want ?

```
 SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        `persons` 
    WHERE 
        `id` NOT IN (
            SELECT 
                DISTINCT(person_id) 
            FROM 
                `rooms_relation`
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it.
Since the number of one person row is more than 1 if there is ANY relation I just had to add this condition.

```
SELECT * FROM persons p
LEFT JOIN rooms_relation r ON r.person_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN persons_relation pr ON pr.person_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN rooms_relation tr ON tr.person_id = pr.teacher_id
WHERE tr.id IS NULL AND r.id IS NULL 
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING count(p.id) = 1;
```